# クッキーの値から配列を作成したい

Tags: php

クッキーに格納されている値から配列を作成したいのですが方法がわかりません．ご教示ください．

### 該当のクッキーの状態

ChromeでF12の開発者モードで見ると以下のようになっています．

名前：search
値：%5B%22%3C%3C%3C%22%2C%22%26%26%26%22%2C%22%2C%2C%2C%22%5D
デコードした値：["<<<","&&&",",,,"]

### 今までにやったこと

そのまま変数に格納してvar_dumpすると文字列扱いです．

```
$sh = $_COOKIE['search'];
var_dump($sh);
```

結果

```
string(19) "["<<<","&&&",",,,"]"
```

配列として初期化しようとしてもうまくゆきません．

```
$sh = array($_COOKIE['search']);
var_dump($sh);
```

結果

```
array(1) { [0]=> string(19) "["<<<","&&&",",,,"]" }
```

### 教えていただきたいこと

`$sh = ["<<<","&&&",",,,"];` のように書いて得られる配列と同じようにしたいです．

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "<<<" [1]=> string(3) "&&&" [2]=> string(3) ",,," }
```

以上 よろしくお願いいたします．

Answer (score 0):

`json_decode()` でいけそうです．

```
$sh = json_decode($_COOKIE['search']);
var_dump($sh);
```

結果

```
array(3) { [0]=> string(3) "<<<" [1]=> string(3) "&&&" [2]=> string(3) ",,," }
```